# Unwanted space in my html table

Tags: html, image, html-table

Here's the [link](http://www.whiterootmedia.com/white_root_media/about_us/team_members/index.html), and as seen at the bottom of the pictures in my table is a 5px space that I would like to go away.

**RELEVANT HTML**

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="#D88830" style="background-color:#555555;" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="../../../images/team_members_dusty_arlia.jpg" alt="Dusty Arlia Picture" border="0" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding:25px; vertical-align:top;" width="550">
      <b>Name</b>: <i>Dusty Arlia</i><br />
      <b>Position</b>: <i>Owner</i><br />
      <b>Start Date</b>: <i>Founded on April 20, 2010</i><br />
      <b>Interests</b>: <i>Loves to snowboard in the winter, play volleyball in the summer, and gives lessons on foosball year round.</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: The extra white space does not appear in FF 3.6.13 on Linux. However it does in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem often when coding HTML emails since you have to use tables.

Put a style of **vertical-align:bottom;** on the image.

The reason given on [this page](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?779478-Why-is-there-a-space-under-image) is that images are inline elements and so space is reserved for typeface decenders... makes sense and works for me.

Comment: This is it.  I wasted hours and you have given me the answer. thank 3 year past of you.

Answer (score 1):

You can put 
style="margin-bottom: -5px" on each of the images, it would be better to declare a class with this attribute and use it on the images.

E.G.

```
<img src="../../../images/team_members_jacquelyn_buffo.jpg" alt="Jacquelyn Buffo Picture" border="0" style="margin-bottom: -5px">
```

Comment: Both of your answers are correct, but I'm a little curious as to how that 5px came to be. I feel like I'm not solving the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<img src="../../../images/team_members_dusty_arlia.jpg"  alt="Dusty Arlia Picture" border="0" style="margin-bottom:-5px" />
```

Comment: Both of your answers are correct, but I'm a little curious as to how that 5px came to be. I feel like I'm not solving the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you added the margin-bottom:-5px -  just wanted to throw out an alternate solution:

```
<img style="float:left;" ... />
```

That fixes the problem as well, might be a better overall solution rather than using negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is several years old by now, but I happened upon it while encountering the same issue.

All you need to do is set `display: block;` on the offending image, whether it be in CSS or inline.

Hope this helps anyone else who finds this answer!